# null is not an object (evaluating 'nativeInterface.configure') in a React-Native app

Tags: android, reactjs, firebase, react-native

I'm working on making this `React Native` app work on `Android`. It's already working on `iOS`.

I've encountered the following error and have no clue where to start looking.

[image]

As far as I can understand it's an issue with `firebase` but not much else is clear. Here is the `firebase` and `react-native` versions:

```sh
"react-native": "0.62.2",
"firebase": "^7.16.1",
"react-native-location": "^2.5.0"
```

I've ran `rm -rm node_modules && npm i`, also cleaned and rebuild the Android project but to no avail.

Edit: After some investigation, the `nativeInterface.configure` is called in `react-native-location`, `index.js`, line 53:

```
exports.configure = function (options) {
    return nativeInterface.configure(options);
};
```

Edit 2: From `logcat` you can see that this error occurs right after this one:

```
020-07-19 21:07:37.884 7994-8029/? E/unknown:ReconnectingWebSocket: Error occurred, shutting down websocket connection: Websocket exception
    java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:215)
```

Comment: As it is evident from the screenshot, `nativeInterface.configure` is called somewhere in the `node_modules` folder. It's nowhere to be found in the project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, what do you know... I ran `react-native link react-native-location` and that fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're trying to use the Firebase JS SDK which is meant for the web? You may have to look into [react-native-firebase](https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase) instead which is a bridge of the iOS and Android SDKs.